# Is the usage "it is not until now……" grammatically correct?

Tags: phrases, inversion

I have heard a lot of sentences including the phrase "until now" at the begining of sentences.

But when I search its inversion format in Google, I hardly find any related sentences which begin with

> "It is not until now ..."

Instead, I get a lot of results such as "until now", "not until" and "it is not until".

So, is the usage "it is not until now" correct or commonly used?

Comment: I think it should be "grammatically".

Comment: Oh ,yeah, you are right~~ Sorry for that mistake. I have corrected it

Comment: No problem - don't apologize. :) I just want to suggest that may be you should wait a few more hours after asking a question to select an answer as your accepted one. If you wait, you will get more answers. If you accept an answer within just an hour, your question will not get as much attention as it would have had you not accepted the first answer so quickly. [Please see this: Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: Thanks for that information! I am new to this site and don't know the mechanism running like that. I will wait for longer time the next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is not until now ...

... is grammatically correct.

It simply means whatever comes after that phrase is false at any moment in time before [now], and is true [now] and most likely true in the future. Note that "now" can be replaced with any moment in time.

For example:

> It is not until *yesterday* that Joe loves boardgames.

Meaning: Before *yesterday*: Joe didn't love boardgames. From *yesterday* onwards: Joe loves boardgames.